# Pluralize the right way table name with 2 words

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Since the command **rails g model ModelName** generates a migration for creating the table, I want to make the name of the table look right. The name of my model is CategoryProduct and its pluralized version should be CategoriesProduct. The model name comes right. But when I run the command to generate the model the migrations comes like this:

```
class CreateCategoryProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :category_products do |t|

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I already changed the file initializers/inflections.rb to made the correction:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'categoryproduct', 'categoriesproduct'
end
```

So, why is it still generating the wrong name with underscore?

Comment: This si a standard way of rails to generate the migrations. Why do you want to change it? I do not have an answer to your question but I would suggest to stick to convention and use Category_products. Which would also make sense, no? Or do your categories only have one product? Think about relationships. Why do you absolutely need this name?

Comment: The only table which will have both words pluralize is join table

Comment: As your model name is `CategoryProduct` category_products is the appropriate table name as per the conventions

Comment: And don't forget rails is convention over configuration so unless you want to configure the app it's better to stick to conventions

Comment: The problem is that I give you an english example. 
Im from Brazil, and the name of the model would be like ProdutoCategoria, and it doesnt work the way it supposed to. The name of the table that it generates is: **produto_categoria**. It should be **produto_categorias**. How do I make that?

Comment: @churros FWIW, while Rails supports Internationalization and Localization, you're going to lose out on some of the clever defaults that Rails offers if you *develop* in another language. Since your English seems quite good, it might be worth your while not to fight uphill the whole way.

Comment: I think i will follow your advice @coreyward. Im loosing too much time trying to make the project work in portuguese. Thanks for the tip. One last question: The collumns of the tables on my database should have english names too? Cause if yes, I'll have to change a lot of things.

Comment: @churros I think the only column names that would matter for inflection purposes are foreign keys (e.g. category_id) or columns used with [Enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

Comment: I think I will work only with english then @coreyward. Im afraid of getting problems in the future if I dont.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your tablename to be categoriesproduct, then create a table with the desired name and specify the tablename in the model.

```
class CategoryProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "categoriesproduct"
end
```

Comment: Yeah @Ambika Sharma,  I could do that, but I wanted to use what rails have generated for me. But I think I will follow corey's advice, I'll try to adapt my project to english. Thanks.